# How does R use weights in regression with the lm function

Tags: r, regression, weighted-regression

If you have a regression model in R and it looks as follows,

`g<-lm(crossx~energy,strongx,weights=sd^-2)`

which i got from this site, [www.stats.uwi.ca](http://www.stats.uwo.ca/faculty/bellhouse/Generalized%20Least%20Squares_DaeroKim.pdf)

and with the data as follows.

`momentum   energy  crossx  sd  sd^-2
   4        0.345   367     17  0.003460208
   6        0.287   311     9   0.012345679
   8        0.251   295     9   0.012345679
  10        0.225   268     7   0.020408163
  12        0.207   253     7   0.020408163
  15        0.186   239     6   0.027777778
  20        0.161   220     6   0.027777778
  30        0.132   213     6   0.027777778
  75        0.084   193     5   0.04
 150        0.06    192    5    0.04`

How does R use the weights in the mdoel? Does it multiply the weights with `enery` and `crossx` to find the new data?

`crossx*(sd-^2) = enery*(sd^-2)`

Or does it get divided?

`crossx/(sd-^2) = enery/(sd^-2)`

Comment: It does weighted least squares. Try doing an internet search for "weighted least squares".

Comment: It does neither of those things.